# How to add new column with source from text in another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have in my sql table data from my website - columns like `transacion_id`, `price`, `product_id` etc... One of the columns is `url_id` and it goes for example like this `myshop_DIRECT_no_name`. How can I add new column to transfer data to sth like this:

```
url_id --- new column (source)
myshop_DIRECT_no_name --- DIRECT
myshop_SEO_no_name --- SEO
myshop_Google_name --- Google
```

I mean a want to add new column with a source generated from text in url_id if in url id there is direct then put direct into new column, when text is seo then put source name seo ect... How can I do it?

Comment: Are you trying to add new columns to your table?

Comment: Yes, but second option is to create a new table with only url-id and source

Comment: Don't add a column, but do use a LEFT JOIN operation in your select queries when retrieving data from the table.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn how can I use JOIN if there's no table to join with?

Comment: You make a table.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn could you explain it? Sorry but I don't understand what do you mean. How can I use join here?

Comment: add the new column, then run an UPDATE statement and SET the value of the new column to the desired value based on the value of the existing column (a CASE statement might make sense)

Comment: SELECT URL

CASE
    WHEN URL LIKE '%SEM' THEN 'Google'
    ELSE 'Others'
END

FROM URL

i did this but it doesn't work...